# Convergent sequence bounded by other sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I never know what to do (or how to start) in proofs.

"Let $u_n, v_n$ be two sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $u_n < v_n < u_{n+1}$. Show that if $v_n$ is bounded, then it converges."

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writting down the given info and have a feel of what it happening.

If $v_n$ is bounded then there must be $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \leq v_n \leq B$. But for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is true that $u_n < v_n$, therefore $u_n < v_n \leq B$ and $u_n$ is also upper bounded.

Now see that if $u_n < v_n < u_{n+1}$ then $u_n < u_{n+1}$ meaning $u_n$ is increasing - so it has a lower bound: $u_1$. By the same triangular inequality you have that $v_{n-1} < u_n < v_n$ and $v_n$ is also increasing. This would complete the proof because $v_n$ is both bounded and monotonic - so it must converge.

Another way to finish it would be to state that since $u_n$ is bounded and monotonic (as we showed), then $u_n$ converges and has a limit $L$ such that:
$$\lim u_n = \lim u_{n+1} = L$$

Hence
$$u_n < v_n < u_{n+1}$$
$$\lim u_n < \lim v_n < \lim v_{n+1}$$
$$L < \lim v_n < L$$

You can see that $\lim v_n = L$ which is a finite number, so $v_n$ must converge.